# Call hierarchy from a certain function

Tags: eclipse, call-hierarchy

**Background:**

Working in eclipse, I have two function: *do_something* and *perform_task*. I know that *do_something* calls a number of other functions which in turn call others (and so on and so on) and somewhere down the line *perform_task* gets called as well.

Since this is a big project, lots of flows and so on, I've already found two different sequences where *do_something* activates *perform_task* through some other sequence of functions.

**Actuall question:**

Is there a way in eclipse to get the call hierarchy of a certain function, but only sequences that will include also a certain other function in the sequence?

Thinking of this in terms of graph paths, we have a directed graph, and instead of asking what are paths to node `x`, I want to know what are the paths to node `x` that include node `y`.

Comment: You may try adding a conditional breakpoint inside the function and as the condition you may write something like Thread.currrentthread().getstacktraceelements contains x.y.z.yourclass.yourmethod

Comment: @guleryuz - thanks for the idea, but in my case that simply is not an option. Also, your idea will cover one option (the one `Thread.currentthread()`), where I am seeking to get insight on all the options...

Comment: is it possible to write some unittest and mock the function perform_task to cover all the sequences situations

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but might be useful enough:

In the **Call Hierarchy** view, there's an option to show the *callees* of the selected method instead of the *callers*. Look at the view toolbar of Call Hiearchy for the two buttons that depict green dots connected with lines; those button toggle between the two modes.

[image]

If you select `do_something` and open the **Call Hierarchy** view on it, then set the mode to **Show Callees** you might be able to explore the various paths out of `do_something` that lead to `perform_task`.